# New featureType?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Anyone know what featureType this icon is (at The Hive)?

[image]

If I remove all 'poi' types, it disappears.  Using:

```
featureType: "poi",
elementType: "labels",
stylers: [
    { visibility: "off" }
]
```

However if I individually remove all the sub-types listed here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapTypeStyleFeatureType

- poi.attraction
- poi.business
- poi.government
- poi.medical
- poi.park
- poi.place_of_worship
- poi.school
- poi.sports_complex

then it still appears.  Are some POI elements on the map not of any of the sub-types, and just belong to the POI parent type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact the answer is, yes,

> "Note however that parent features may include some additional
>   features that are not included in one of their child feature types."

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapTypeStyleFeatureType